# Downloading a file using CURL statement in Python wit headers and data

Tags: python, file, csv, curl, download

I'm working to automate, via Python and Windows Task Scheduler, a daily download from an internal website.  When I do things manually, I go to a browser page, fill out the parameters on a form, then click "submit"; the browser tells me it is preparing my download CSV file and then, after some time, it dumps the CSV to my hard drive.  I have the CURL statement and thought I'd try to go that route, but I cannot figure out how to automate this, and I can't use things like AutoHotKey because GUI interactions are not allowed by Task Scheduler.  Here's what I've tried so far, but all I get in the end is the resulting HTML, not a CSV download:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import time
import shutil

url = <<this is where the internal web page URL goes>>
str="&"
values = ('sequelPath=<<specific path to executable that creates the file>>',
          'bdatedate=<<here's where the start date goes>>',
          'edate=<<here's where the end date goes>>'
          )

headers = { 'Cookie': JSESSIONID=<<cookie goes here>>; acStatus_Button1=open; acStatus_Button0=close; acStatus_Button2=close; acStatus_Button3=close',
            'Origin': '<<originating URL goes here>>',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
            'Referer': 'http://<<internal URL, same as originating URL above>>/exec/<<remainder of URL>>',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive'
            }
data = str.join(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
myfile = open('myfile.csv', 'wb')
shutil.copyfileobj(response.fp, myfile)
myfile.close()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your internal web page handles requests, it's difficult to figure out what's wrong.

Here's an example from Python's docs to do an HTTP POST:
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#data

What I see missing is url-encoding your data.

Also, `str` is the class for a string, so you shouldn't use that as your variable name.

For help debugging, you can use Chrome or Firefox's developer tools to see what exactly the headers and values are needed

How are you generating the JSESSIONID?  Isn't it unique for each request, which requires you to send a request first to get a valid one?

Comment: Thanks Addison.  I actually figured it out using Selenium instead.  Seems that Windows Task Scheduler doesn't consider it an issue if Selenium pushes commands through the browser to get this done.  I'm not sure POST would work, as the download is triggered by a Javascript, not a submit.  Maybe I'm wrong about that, but the Selenium fix seems to be working repeatedly, so I'm not messing with it.  Thanks again.